# Simple event mediator

Tags: php, php5, mediator

I was trying to explain the mediator pattern to a new developer, and ended up writing a simple event mediator. Thoughts?

**EventMediator**

```
class EventMediator {
    private $events = array();

    public function attach($event, Closure $callback) {
        if(!is_string($event)) throw new \InvalidArgumentException();

        $event = strtolower(trim($event));
        if(!isset($this->events[$event])) $this->events[$event] = array();

        $this->events[$event][] = $callback;

        return $this;
    }

    public function trigger($event, $data = null) {
        if(!is_string($event)) throw new \InvalidArgumentException();

        $event = strtolower(trim($event));
        if(!isset($this->events[$event])) return false;

        foreach($this->events[$event] as $callback) $callback($event, $data);

        return true;
    }

    public function getEvents() { return $this->events; }
}
```

**EventfulTrait**

```
trait EventfulTrait {

    private $eventMediator;

    public function attachEventMediator(EventMediator $eventMediator) {
        $this->eventMediator = $eventMediator;
        return $this;
    }

    public function detachEventMediator() {
        $this->eventMediator = null;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEventMediator() {
        return $this->eventMediator;
    }

    public function attachEvent($name, $callback) {
        if(!is_null($this->eventMediator)) $this->eventMediator->attach($name, $callback);
        return $this;
    }

    public function triggerEvent($name, $data = null) {
        if(!is_null($this->eventMediator)) return $this->eventMediator->trigger($name, $data);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
require "EventMediator.php";
require "EventfulTrait.php";

class Log {
    public function write($message) {
        echo "{$message}\n";
    }
}

class Eventful {
    use EventfulTrait;

    private $log;

    public function __construct() { $this->log = new Log(); }

    public function attachLoadEvent() {
        $self = $this;
        $log  = $this->log;
        $this->attachEvent(
            "load", function() use($self, $log) {
                $self->runOutOfNames();
                $log->write("log message");
            }
        );
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        $this->triggerEvent("load");
        $this->triggerEvent("event1");
    }

    public function doSomethingElse() {
        $this->triggerEvent("load");
        $this->triggerEvent("event1");
        $this->triggerEvent("event2");
    }

    public function runOutOfNames() { echo "load\n"; }
}

$eventMediator = new EventMediator();
$eventMediator->attach("event1", function() { echo "event1\n"; });
$eventMediator->attach("event2", function() { echo "event2\n"; });
$eventMediator->attach("done", function() { echo "done\n"; });

$eventful = new Eventful();
$eventful->attachEventMediator($eventMediator);
$eventful->attachLoadEvent();
$eventful->doSomething();
$eventful->doSomethingElse();

$eventMediator->trigger("load");
$eventMediator->trigger("done");
```

This will echo:

```
load
log message
event1
load
log message
event1
event2
load
log message
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very clean looking code base, so congrats getting that down. I also think that the the way you implemented the pattern worked out very well.

I don't have much to say, it's mostly just formatting.

- Throughout, you insist on keeping block sections condensed to one line. It's perfectly okay to add the brackets and break apart the code into multiple lines.
- In `attach()`, you return the current object. I don't see why you're doing so as in the example you didn't utilize this feature. Don't write code that's not in use yet!
- You might consider moving `strtolower(trim($event))` to a function with the appropriate parameters. Don't repeat yourself.
- Why is `!isset($this->events[$event])` returning false. I would expect an exception to be throw, that way if the code needs to watch for other errors later on, `false` could mean many things.
- `attachEventMediator` I think needs a new name. You're not just *attaching* a mediator, you're *setting* it. If you had support for multiple mediators, then attach would be appropriate. Similarly, `detach` should be *remove* or *delete*.
- Perhaps in replace of `echo "{$message}\n";`, you could use the `sprintf` function. I personally think this would clear up the line.
- To improve your dependency injection  in `Eventful`, pass the `Log` as a parameter.
- Will the message always be `"log message"`? Maybe pass that as an argument.

Overall I think the code is well-written. A couple more comments and better example code could have improved it even more!